# What is the best way to cache/persist a menu in an ASP.NET application on postback

Tags: asp.net, caching

What is the best way to cache a menu in an ASP.NET application for optimized performance? 
Please note that the menu is being constructed based on user role and other criteria such as selection of certain controls/sections on the page, and data for the menu is fetched from the database.
Currently, the menu is being constructed on every postback of each page. How can this be avoided ?
Should I enable view state for the user control which contains the menu ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to cache a page's output, we need to specify an `@OutputCache` directive at the top of the page.

There is an attribute `VaryByParam`, which can be used to vary the cache based on query string parameters.

It is worthwhile to have a look at this [blog](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6158/Caching-in-ASP-NET) on caching.

Comment: Edited the question to help you understand the problem I'm facing.